# Lorentz transformations an EM fields

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

When deriving the Lorentz transformation equations in undergraduate physics classes, teachers typically analyze the behavior of an ideal clock and a rigid bar.  Once the behavior of clocks and rods is explained, the concept of a 4-vector is introduced.  We are told 4-vectors all transform according to the Lorentz transformations.  This is then used to show how EM fields transform between inertial frames.  Are there similar simple thought experiemnts that allow you to derive transformation equations starting with E and B fields rather than clocks and rods.  If so, can someone provide a reference?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually 4-potential of EM field isn't Lorentz 4-vector.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking for, but the page [here](http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/mrr/MRRtalk.html) gives some examples of how a deflection caused by an electric field can transform into one caused by a magnetic field in another frame, if we *assume* effects derived from the Lorentz contraction like length contraction. I think it should be possible to reverse the logic and derive things like length contraction from the requirement that different frames make equivalent predictions about the behavior of charges when Maxwell's equations are applied in each frame.